# Mysql result is a resource but doesn't display

Tags: php, mysql

Okay so i have this code:

```
if (isset($_GET['book'])) {

$query= "SELECT  book_id, title, authors.`author` , publishers.`publisher` , formats.`format` , genres.`genre` , usersdb.users.username, pages, isbn, description, DATE_FORMAT( books.`release_date` ,  '%M, %d, %Y' ) AS  `release_date` 
    FROM books
    INNER JOIN  `authors` ON (  `authors`.`author_id` =  `books`.`author_id` ) 
    INNER JOIN  `publishers` ON (  `publishers`.`publisher_id` =  `books`.`publisher_id` ) 
    INNER JOIN  `formats` ON (  `formats`.`format_id` =  `books`.`format_id` ) 
    INNER JOIN  `genres` ON (  `genres`.`genre_id` =  `books`.`genre_id` ) 
    INNER JOIN usersdb.users ON ( usersdb.users.user_id = bookdb.books.user_id ) 
    WHERE books.book_id= ".$_GET['book']."";
    $query=@mysql_query ($query, $dbc1);

if ($query) {
var_dump ($query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

echo '<h1>'.$row['title'].'</h1>
  <p>'.$row['author'].'</p>
  <p>'.$row['publisher'].'</p>
  <p>'.$row['format'].'</p>
  <p>'.$row['genre'].'</p>
  <p>'.$row['pages'].'</p>
  <p>'.$row['isbn'].'</p>
  <p>'.$row['release_date'].'</p>
  <p>'.$row['description'].'</p>
  <p>'.$row['username'].'</p>';
}
}
}
```

It works absolutely fine for some of the entries and all the information is displayed correctly and is fine, but for new entries the information doesn't display at all for some reason.

The mysql query runs correctly and as you can see the I have done a var_dump() and that returns `resource(11, mysql result)` so the resource is definitely there it just doesn't seem to get run through the while statement.

If you can see why this is occurring that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Run `echo mysql_num_rows($query);` to see how many rows got returned. Maybe it's just an empty result and the error is actually somewhere else.

Comment: Try to use different variable in    $query=@mysql_query ($query, $dbc1);

Comment: If you have a problem that you can't find and you are using an `@` operator anywhere in your code, remove it, it's probably masking it. There is a rule for when to use the `@` operator - don't. Also, while there is technically no problem with the way you have done it, declaring the query string in `$query` and then assigning the result resource to `$query` is potentially confusing and definitely bad practice. Put the result of `mysql_query()` in a new variable. I know PHP is *very* loosely typed but there is little to be gained by keeping the variable count minimal unless you have thousands.

Comment: Of course, really the answer here is *not to use the mysql extension* - both mysqli and PDO_mysql are available virtually everywhere now, so you should use one of those instead (I recommend PDO, YMMV)

Comment: so I ran the `echo mysql_num_rows($query);` and on the ones that are displaying correctly it returned 1 on the ones that didn't it returned 0. So it does look like the error is somewhere else.

Comment: Also I've just noticed the gaping [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/) hole in your code. Try this: load you page with `http://path/to/your/page.php?book=1%20OR%201%3D1` and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just remove the "@", you will see that there's maybe an error. Globally in PHP, the use of "@" is a mistake. You may never use it.

Comment: `mysql_query()` returns false and not a resource if it fails, so the @ is not hiding any problems here.

Comment: @Niko Granted, and I concur that this is not the answer (it's barely even *an* answer) but it doesn't mean that using `@` is ever acceptable. It is like `goto` - acceptable uses are so few and far between, and it's so easy to write massive holes in your confusing and un-debuggable code when you use it, that it's easier to just say "never user it". There is one place I ever use `@` and that is `fopen();` and even then I only use it to keep the logs tidy, since I *never* have `display_errors` on in production. Sorry, I guess this annoys me disproportionately - rant over.

Comment: Even if mysql returns a result, a notice or a warning will not fail your request but trigger a message that you're trying to hide with the "@". So if you have a problem, first reflex => remove all error hiding.

Answer (score -1):

Try `echo mysql_num_rows($query)` if any records are being fetched.

If it returns some value,
try removing @,it might be the cause of error

Comment: do not use $query everywhere,try changing the name of variables